# Javascript if statement doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm trying to create a small survey with a score. I want to make it so once user reaches score "4", it alerts some message. I wrote if statment for it, but for some reason it never alerts. But if I manually change score variable to 4, everything works as expected.

Where am I going wrong?

Here's the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/uy9kq9mx/

```
<script>
var score = 0;

function checkQuestionOne (){

    var jautViens = document.getElementById('jaut1Pirm');
    var jautDivi = document.getElementById('Jaut1Otra');
    var jautTris = document.getElementById('Jaut1Tres');
    var jautCetri = document.getElementById('Jaut1Cetu');

    if(jautViens.checked) {
        alert(++score)
    }else if(jautDivi.checked || jautTris.checked || jautCetri.checked) {
        alert("Nepareizi")
    }else{
        alert("Izvēlies opciju!")
    }
}

if (score == 4){
    alert(score);

}else{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the condition if the function

```js
var score = 0;

function checkQuestionOne() {

    var jautViens = document.getElementById('jaut1Pirm');
    var jautDivi = document.getElementById('Jaut1Otra');
    var jautTris = document.getElementById('Jaut1Tres');
    var jautCetri = document.getElementById('Jaut1Cetu');

    if (jautViens.checked) {
        ++score;
        //since value of score is changed only in this block you can place the if block here
        if (score == 4) {
            alert('score is 4');
        }
    } else if (jautDivi.checked || jautTris.checked || jautCetri.checked) {
        alert("Nepareizi")
    } else {
        alert("Izvēlies opciju!")
    }
    
    //keep the if block here, if there are multiple blocks in which the value of score is changed
}
```

```html
<h1>Pirmais jautājums (1. pareizā)</h1>
<input type="radio" name="jaut1" id="jaut1Pirm" value="pirma" />Šī ir pirmā atbilde
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="jaut1" id="Jaut1Otra" value="otra" />Šī ir otrā atbilde
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="jaut1" id="Jaut1Tres" value="tresa" />Šī ir trešā atbilde
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="jaut1" id="Jaut1Cetu" value="ceturta" />Šī ir ceturtā atbilde
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="submit" onclick="checkQuestionOne();">Spied</button>
```

When you keep it outside of the function, the `if` condition is evaluated only once, but you need to check it everytime the value of `score` is changed.

Comment: `if (++score == 4) {
            alert('score is 4');
        }` can also be used.